# Sharding and indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, sharding

I want to shard my database but I'm not professional in this topic. So here are my considerations. Though sharding key is excellent index for directing requests to the right nodes, what about the rest of indexes that will be defined upon my tables? I want requests referencing those indexes to be delivered to the right nodes as well so that only one node process the request. As far as I understand for this purpose some centralized index nodes must exist. So my question is whether this functionality is already present in RDBMS like MYSQL or should I use other special products.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com/), I live and breath sharding every day...

I would advise here that if you shard according to column A for example, a WHERE with columnA=xx will go to a single shrad. WHERE columnB=xx will have to go all shards because there might be columnB=xx in all of them. Unless columnA and columnB are related. And then you really need to save the relation in a mapping table. 
I can say that running on all DBs can be super-fast, you need to run in parallel and merge results. At ScaleBase we support merging ORDER BY, GROUP BY etc. It's not easy...

Hey see more info in my blog: http://database-scalability.blogspot.com

Comment: Yes, this is what I don't understand. If you had separate nodes dedicated to db indexes (record physical position + machine id) you could make each query referencing B column go to only those machines where the data actually are! This is faster!

Answer (score 0):

Andrey, what you are describing is exactly how the Clustrix database works, where data and indexes are automatically distributed, then queries are distributed across nodes. Clustrix "[brings the query to the data](http://www.clustrix.com/Portals/146389/docs/clustrix_a_new_approach.pdf)" and has a shared-nothing architecture (so no centralized index is needed). MySQL does not have any built-in functionality for distributed computing, and while there are various bolt-on options, they will ultimately encounter scaling limits when the centralized resources limits are hit.